# How do i center this image inside my view?

Tags: android

I am simply trying to center my imageview10 inside my color view how do i go about doing this? I'm not used to using linear layout so i am not too familiar on how to do this can someone help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/colorView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:background="@color/outlineColor"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        
        
        
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productNames"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Grocery"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: LInearLayout can't do. Use ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to center the ImageView. You also need to make the LinearLayout's width to match the parent using this attribute `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/colorView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/outlineColor"


        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productNames"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Grocery"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />


</LinearLayout>
```